# Kiel vi dirus "welcome back" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi pensis pri "Rebonvenon" aŭ "Bonvenon denove" sed tio ne vere plaĉas al mi. Ĉu ekzistas pli bona traduko por tio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Rebonvenon" estas tute bona. Ni diras tion en Lernu kun Logano.

Alternative: bonan revenon.

Comment: Oh, okej, dankon! Via alternativo estas ankaŭ bona (kaj simila de kio Antonia proponis fakte).

Comment: Nu, fakte mi opinias ke "bonrevenon" estas kasxita elizio de la adjektivo. "Bonan revenon" estas uzata de Renato Corsetti kaj aliaj. "Rebonvenon" sekvas le jena logiko - vi jam scias ke vi estas bonvena, kaj mi rebonvenigas vin (bonvenigas vin je la dua aux plia fojo).

Answer (score 7):

Mi dirus "bonrevenon"
(Mi deziras al vi bonan revenon.) Laŭ mi "rebonvenon" sekvus alian logikon (Mi deziras al vi bonvenon reen.)

Comment: Dankon, kvankam mi ŝatas la respondon de Tomaso, mi ankaŭ ŝatas kion vi diferencas rebonvenon kaj bonrevenon!